# Generate 37 numbers between 0 and 36 in php

Tags: php, html

I want to generate 37 numbers between 0 and 36. I want to see these numbers in a horizontal list.

The numbers that are generated twice or more must be shown below that list in another horizontal list.

Can someone help me here?

I have this so far:

```
<?php

    $numberOfSpins = 37;
    $numberArray = array();

    // Start table
    echo '<table><tr>';

    // print out the table headers
    for ($x = 0; $x < 37; $x++) echo '<th style="font-weight:bold; color:#09f;">'.$x.'</th>';

    // Fill $numberArray with random numbers
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfSpins; $i++) 
        array_push($numberArray, mt_rand(0,36));

    echo '</tr><tr>';       

    // Count value frequency using PHP function array_count_value()
    $resultArray = array_count_values($numberArray);

    // Start from 0 since you are generating numbers from 0 to 36
    for ($i = 0; $i < 37; $i++)
    {
        // array_count_values() returns an associative array (the key of
        // each array item is the value it was counting and the value is the 
        // occurrence count; [key]->value).
        if (isset($resultArray[$i])) 
            echo '<td>'.$resultArray[$i].'</td>';
        else 
            echo '<td>0</td>';
    }

   echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: They must be random numbers?

Comment: Yes please. The program will be used to develop a roulette system so we can see how the system holds up on a larger scale.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
  //How many numbers the program will print 
  $cycles = 36; 

  //min random number
  $minNumber = 0;

  //Max random number
  $maxNumber = 37; 

  //all numbers
  $numbers = array();

  //repeated numbers
  $repeated_numbers = array();

  //repeated numbers string, th and td
  $r_numbers = "";
  $th = "";
  $td = "";
  for ($i=1; $i < $cycles + 1; $i++) { 
    //get a random number 
    $rand_n = rand($minNumber, $maxNumber);

    // create a td and th with the random number and the number index
    $td .= "<td> $rand_n </td>";
    $th .= "<th>Number $i </th>";

    //if the new random number is already on the number array means that is repeated
    // eif not, we store it in the all numbers array
    if (in_array($rand_n, $numbers))
        array_push($repeated_numbers, $rand_n);
    else
        array_push($numbers, $rand_n);
  }

  // we concat all the result to make a table and echo it out
  $table = "<table border='1'><thead>$th</thead><tbody>$td</tbody></table>";
  echo $table;

  //echo the repeated numbers only
  echo "<br> <br> <hr> Repeated Numbers = ";
  foreach ($repeated_numbers as $num) {
    echo "$num |";
  }

  echo "Total Repeated Numbers : " . count($repeated_numbers);
```

**Update**

Use this for implementation instead the above foreach to avoid the last `|`

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($repeated_numbers); $i++) {
    if ($i + 1 == count($repeated_numbers)) {
        echo "$repeated_numbers[$i]";
        continue;
    }
    echo "$repeated_numbers[$i] |";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you add how many different numbers are repeated below the repeated numbers line?

Comment: Just need to add `echo "Total Repeated Numbers : " . count($repeated_numbers);` to the bottom

Comment: Thanks, it's working although I can't remove the last | for some strange reason. BTW do you have skype? Can we chat on skype?

Comment: @AmroAwad no. You can remove the last `|` by using a for loop and checking for the last record. if it is the last, just dont echo it.